# React native inspect element on desktop

Tags: react-native

Using react native on windows, is there anyway I can inspect elements and their styles in Chrome on my desktop, like you would with a webpage?

I have the dev tools on my device, but would like to use my desktop to debug.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger
I haven't used it. But maybe you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install the react-devtools package globally using this command : 
        npm install -g react-devtools

Step 2: Goto your Project Directory and run project

Step 3: Open other command prompt and goto at Project Directory and run following command
        react-devtools

Step 4: It will open "React Developer Tools"

Step 5: Now at Emulator press Ctrl+M and select Toggle Inspector

Step 6: Now you can inspect in React Developer Tools

for more information go at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#react-developer-tools

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Xe7.png)

Comment: What if I am testing on a real device?

Comment: I found The answer here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/development-mode/ All that I have to do is shaking the device! Thank you!